# ERROR: Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, type-conversion, cast

I unfortunately have some bad data and need to work around it. I have a Parcel column in a spreadsheet with some parcels that have inadvertently been converted to floating point numbers. I posted a question to solve this problem [Handling sql column with mixed varchar and float data types](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137909/handling-sql-column-with-mixed-varchar-and-float-data-types)
However, now I am getting an error when I try the following code:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST([Parcel Number 2(max)] AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL) AS NVARCHAR(255))
FROM XLSIMPORT WHERE [Parcel Number 2(max)] = '1.4515020001e+012'
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line 41
Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.
```

Comment: Are you certain that Excel has actually converted the number? If you don't set a datatype for a cell & paste a long number in, it'll display it as 1.xe+nnn, but the real value is still there (format cells->category->number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to indicate that the `DECIMAL` datatype is not defined with the correct precision and scale. The default is `DECIMAL(18,0)`, but something may have happened with your defaults? When I run the query below as you have (just changed to a table variable and added the precision and scale), I am not receiving any error.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
([Parcel Number 2(max)] FLOAT)

INSERT INTO @test
        ( [Parcel Number 2(max)] )
VALUES  ( '1.4515020001e+012'  -- Parcel Number 2(max) - float
          )

SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST([Parcel Number 2(max)] AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(18,0)) AS NVARCHAR(255))
FROM @test WHERE [Parcel Number 2(max)] = '1.4515020001e+012'
```

As an FYI, I do get an arithmetic overflow if I try `DECIMAL(12,0)`.